# Elasticsearch: how to search a user_defined field?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I use mysql to store user data, and search the data by Elasticsearch. For mysql, I have a user defined field, this field can store a JSON format data.

the example data like this:

```
data1 = 
{
"name" : "test1",
"age": 10,
"user_defined": {
  "a" : "aaa",
  "b" : "bbb",
  "c" : "ccc",
  .....
  }
}

data2 = 
{
"name" : "test2",
"age": 20,
"user_defined": {
  "d" : "ddd",
  "e" : "eee",
  "f" : "fff",
  .....
  }
}
```

For user_defined field, the number of keys is not fixed, the type of values all are string, I hope each key can be searched, how to define the mapping? how to search this kind of data by Elasticsearch?

Anyone has good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the mapping of the `user_defined` as [`"type": "object"`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html), like this:

```
PUT your_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": { 
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "user_defined": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thereafter, you can index your documents and search them easily with the [Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html)

```
POST your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match" : {
       "user_defined.a" : "aaa"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you mean I doesn't need to tell ES the detail of `user_defined` filed?

Comment: Depending on the kind of queries you want to run afterwards on those values, you don't need to, ES will figure it out for you, and since all values are string, it will be easy.

Comment: I found a problem. If .`a` is an Chinese character, I cannot search it by `user_defined.a`.

Comment: That's a different issue in my opinion, i.e. there's an encoding issue somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Every field in a document in Elasticsearch is indexed and searchable by default.

Elasticsearch provides a [Search Lite API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/search-lite.html) and a [Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-dsl-intro.html) for searching.

Comment: I think it is not a answer